# Is there any way to change the colour of a string within a string in c++

Tags: c++, console

This is the code, I have a string called `Battlelogs` which stores the result of all the battles that take place in a turn, `FactionFighter` is the name of the attacker and `FactionDefender` is the name of the defending faction, there are 14 total factions and it is set to one of those prior to the fight, all of this works but the problem is each faction has their own colour, and I want to have the text show the colour of the faction on their name.

So if the rebels are grey and the bandit horde are green, it would display the word rebels in grey and bandit horde in green, I know how to change the colour of text that is put out with cout, but as this is strings within strings I don't know how to do it.

```
Battlelogs += FactionFighter + " attempted to raid the lands of the " + FactionDefender + " but were unsuccessful\n";
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Some consoles support escape codes (just plain text interleaved with your output) to change color and/or formatting. However it's not really portable...

Comment: Check http://vt100.net/, it's supported from ancient times in *nix and in Windows starting from Windows 10 (check MSDN for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx)